# How to set an Infragistics ribbon group visiblity to false in code

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

How to set an Infragistics ribbon group visiblity to false in code?

I am trying to hide an Infragistics group box depending on the users Dpi on form load.
There is a button inside the group area that I have managed to hide using:

```
utmApplicant.Tools("Match").SharedProps.Visible = False
```

I assumed I could use the same code to hide the group box but it keeps saying that the key has not been found but I am using the right key. Any suggestions?

I'm using VB.NET

Comment: you'll have to show us the code that didn't work, as opposed the the code that does...

Comment: utmApplicant.Tools("Contact").SharedProps.Visible = False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to what kind of object you are referring to.

In an Infragistics `UltraToolbarsManager` there is a `Ribbon` object that contains a Tabs collection. Each Tab contains a Groups collection and each Group contains one or more Tools.

So, to hide the first tab (I have used an integer to index, but the key string works as well)

```
utmApplicant.Ribbon.Tabs(0).Visible = False
```

To hide a specific group inside the first tab

```
utmApplicant.Ribbon.Tabs(0).Groups(0).Visible = False
```

To hide a particular tool assigned to a specific Group (a label, a button, a textbox or other kind of UI widgets) you could use this syntax

```
utmApplicant.Ribbon.Tabs(0)
                   .Groups(0)
                   .Tools("Match")
                   .InstanceProps.Visible = DefaultableBoolean.False
```

Tools are kept in the global collection under the UltraToolbarsManager hierarchy root but when assigned to a specific Group could be referenced with the syntax above.

Comment: the tab contains 'Applicant' and inside that contains 'Contact' and 'Record'